# How to search for *~ as in anything ending with ~ in a bash script

Tags: bash, character

I'm writing a Bash script and I need to find and move/delete all files with names ending in ~ or beginning and ending with #, that is file~ or #file#, emacs junk files.

I'm trying to use [ -f *~ ] && ( ... move or delete those files ... ) to determine if any files of this kind exist before I try to do anything to them, so as not to get error messages from the rm or mv function if they don't find the files. However, this results in "binary operator expected". I think it has something to do with the fact that ~ is an unary operator. Is there a way to make it work as intended?

Comment: If it is just about avoiding error messages from `rm`, why not just use `rm -f`?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with what you were doing originally for current directory (not any slower than `find`), though not as one-liney.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *"~"; do
  if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    #do something with $file
  fi
done
```

Also, "binary operator expected" is just coming from bash expecting a single argument for the "-f" operator, whereas `*~` can expand to multiple arguments, e.g.

```
$ mkdir test && cd test
$ touch "1~"
$ if [ -f *"~" ]; then echo "Confirmed file ending in ~"; fi 
Confirmed file ending in ~
$ touch {2..10}"~" && echo *"~" 
1~ 10~ 2~ 3~ 4~ 5~ 6~ 7~ 8~ 9~
$ if [ -f *"~" ]; then echo "Confirmed file ending in ~"; fi
bash: [: too many arguments
$ if [ -f "arg1" "arg2"; then echo "Confirmed file ending in ~"; fi
bash: [: arg1: binary operator expected
```

Not positive why errors are different for the two cases, but pretty sure either error can result depending on expansion.

Comment: With 2 arguments (whether explicit or the result of expansion) you get 'binary operator expected', with more you get 'too many arguments', but the crucial point, as you correctly state, is that the **file-testing operators such as `-f` are not designed to be used with globbing patterns - only with a single, literal path**.

Comment: D'oh, could have avoided some confusion if I tested with 3 arguments, thanks for the info.

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for the neat `touch` + brace expansion trick for creating test files - very handy.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem stems from the fact that **file-testing operators such as `-f` are not designed to be used with globbing patterns - only with a single, literal path.**

You can simply let bash's path expansion (globbing) do the work:

Note: The approaches below are an alternative to using a loop (as demonstrated in @BroSlow's answer).

**Simplest approach**:

```
 rm -f *'~' '#'*'#'
```

This removes all matching files, if any, and, if there are no matches, does nothing (and outputs nothing and reports exit code 0) - thanks to the `-f` option (tip of the hat to @chris).

**Caveat**: This also silently removes files marked as read-only, IF you have sufficient permissions to make them writable. In other words: if files match that you have intentionally marked as read-only, they will still get removed.

Also, if *directories* happen to match, they will NOT be removed, an error message will be displayed and the exit code will be 1 - matching *files*, however, are still removed.
At your own peril you may add `-r` to also quietly remove any matching directories (whether they're empty or not).

**Using find, if explicitly ruling out directories is desired:**

To avoid matching directories, you can use `find`, but to make it safe, the command gets lengthy:

```
# delete
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*~' -delete  -or -name '#*#' -delete

# move
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \
         -name '*~' -exec mv {} /tmp/ \;  -or \
         -name '#*#' -exec mv {} /tmp/ \;
```

(Two general notes on `find`:

- The path *itself* (`.`, in this case) is by default *included* in the set of items (not a concern in this particular case due to excluding directories from matching) - to avoid that, add `-mindepth 1`.
- Terminating the command passed to the `-exec` primary with `+` rather than `\;` is generally preferable, as `find` then substitutes as many matches as will safely fit for `{}`, resulting in much fewer invocations (typically just 1) of the command (assuming, of course, that your command can take argument lists of variable length) - this is similar to `xargs`' behavior.
  Here's the **catch**: `-exec` only accepts commands terminated with `+` if `{}` is the command's *last* argument (and will otherwise fail with the misleading error message `find: missing argument to '-exec'`).
  Thus, in the case at hand `+` *cannot* be used, because the `mv` command's last argument must be the target.

)

Answer (score 0):

The `find` command is generally used for things of this nature. It even has a built-in `-delete` flag.

```
find -name '*~' -delete
```

or, with `xargs` (to move, for example)

```
# Moves files to /tmp using the replacement string specified with the -I flag
find -name '*~' -print0 | xargs -0 -I _ mv _ /tmp/
```

If you prefer to use `xargs` for deletion as well, you can do away with the use of `-I`

```
find -name '*~' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Note the use of the `-print0` and `-0` flags to specify null-terminated paths. This allows paths with spaces to run properly. Without -0, filenames with spaces (including spaces anywhere in the path) will be treated as two separate (possibly invalid) paths.

Comment: Note that the OP didn't say he's on linux (although one can assume this when he says he's using bash). -delete and -print0 are gnu extensions that won't work on the standard unix commands.

Comment: Indeed. I assumed (possibly incorrectly) that bash -> Linux. I also left out the path field required on non-GNU `find`s for this reason.

Comment: `-print0` and `-delete` do work on OSX, but the path argument is indeed required; i.e.: `find . -name ....` to target the current dir. Also, the `find` commands as specified will look for matching files in the target directory's entire *subtree* - to **limit processing to items directly located in the target directory**, append `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` to the `find` command; also: add `-type -f` to limit matching to files only.

Comment: Using `... -print0 | xargs -0 -I ...` is a great technique in general, but in this case you could simply use `find`'s `-exec` primary (no need for `xargs`): instead of `-print0`, use `-exec mv {} /tmp/ \;`.

Answer (score 0):

The shell will expand your *~ to a list of all files ending in ~. So if you have more than one of them, they all will be in the parameter list of -f, but -f handles only one parameter.

Try

```
find . -name "*~" -print | xargs rm
```

and read about the parameters to find if you want to stop it from recursing your whole directory structure.

Comment: As specified, this command will not handle filenames with embedded spaces correctly.
Append `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` to the `find` command to **only process matching files/folders directly located in the specified folder** (`.`).
To limit matching to files only, add `-type f`.